# Problems with HTTP-requests out of hadoop map job

Tags: http, sockets, hadoop

I have a process where I aggregate data and send a request via a http POST out of a map job. I have to wait for the results. Unfortunately I encounter problems with this approach.

When doing so, there is a loss of data during the sending. We managed to investigate this issue to a point where we know that the communication "destroys" sockets and therefore data is lost. Did anyone has experience in doing http POST requests out of a mapper and what to be aware of?

some sample code; mapper:

```
public void map(final LongWritable key, final Text value, Context context) throws IOException {
        String someData = value.toString();
        buffer.add(someData);

        if (buffer.size() >=  MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                emit(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

in "emit" I serialize the data (this is fine, I tested this several times) and send it afterwards; sender:

```
byte[] received = null;
    URL connAddress = new URL(someComponentToBeAdressed);
    HttpURLConnection urlConn;
    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) connAddress.openConnection();

    urlConn.setDoInput(true);
    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/plain");

    urlConn.getOutputStream().write(serialized_buffer);
    urlConn.getOutputStream().flush();
    urlConn.getOutputStream().close();

    received = IOUtils.toByteArray(urlConn.getInputStream());
    urlConn.disconnect();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you remembering to flush / close the socket when you are done?

Comment: I added some code above. I didn't work with sockets directly. Because of that it is a strange behaviour that sockets are out of order when sending data.

Comment: Are you calling the emit method in the close method of the mapper? If you have data left in your buffer, and your not emitting it in the close method then this is probably where your loss of data is occuring

Comment: yes, i call it in cleanup again. We know that of 100 data objects send at least 2/3 are lost on the way to the destination. We implemented a dummy which sends the data gained back and count on the other side how information arrives. if we send 100, on the other side roughly 35 arrive. when sending back all 35 documents are successfully submited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we where able to fix this issue. It was no error in hadoop, the error lies in our apache tomcat configuration some timeouts where set for a to small time period. for some bigger chunks of data we overcome the time for the timeout and get errors. unfortunately the exceptions where not that helpful.